# How to find objects by a couple of tags and names in a small area specifying the coordinate only once?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I want to use overpass to search for a couple of tags and names in a small area, e.g. 50 meter around a geocoordinate:

```
nwr(around:50,51.477,0.0);
(
  nwr[building=industrial][name~"Chemi|chemi"];
  nwr[industrial][name~"Chemi|chemi"];
);
out count;
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I understood `( )` is for union (equalling a logic OR) and consecutive commands behave like an AND. Yet what I get as a response from overpass seems to be the data on the whole world. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The following request worked for me:

```
nwr(around:50000,31.962985, 35.915135)->.searchArea;
(
  nwr[building=industrial][name~"Chemi|chemi"](area.searchArea);
  nwr[industrial][name~"Chemi|chemi"](area.searchArea);
);
out count;
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Besides requiring to have the `(area.searchArea)` condition in each line I've got the suspicion that the first line could cause unnecessary nwr objects to be processed by the the overpass server
instead of just defining the search area.

Comment: Your searchArea doesn’t work with relations, unfortunately. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457273/overpass-api-get-building-in-area-with-landuse-x for more details and ways to fix it.